# Regex - does "or" require creating groups?

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I use boost regex. I have created the following regex witch matches numbers from range [10-31]:

```
[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]
```

I want to use that regex with additional matching for example:

```
<tag-[[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]]>
```

but it doesn't work. It works when I create group:

```
<tag-([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])>
```

For string `<tag-22>` I get two groups: `<tag-22>, 22`

Is it possible to create such regex without using groups ?

Comment: Use `<tag-(?:[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])>`

Comment: Is it the only way ? Could you explain way using additional  [ ] doesn't work ?

Comment:  What @WiktorStribiżew is showing is called non-capturing parentheses -- used for conceptual grouping without creating ("capturing") a group. This is the correct way.

Comment: No, you may also use branch reset groups that are also non-capturing, `<tag-(?|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])>`, but that is not necessary.